# How do i put a word into an array

Tags: arrays, c, random, menu

so this is part of a kind of menu, the only problemis that the word is not getting into the  array "frase" i have already tried with frase  [ ] = "the word" but idk why it wont work

```
if(lvl==1)
    {
        printf("lvl 1\n");
        if (opc==1)
        {
            printf("Animales\n");
            a = rand() %3 + 1;
            printf("%d", a);
            if (a=1)
                frase  <= "pato";
            if (a=2)
                frase <="ganso";
            if (a=3)
                frase <= "avispa";
        }
        if (opc==2)
        {
            printf("comida\n");
            a = rand() %3 + 1;
            if (a=1)
                frase <="pasta";
            if (a=2)
                frase <="pizza";
            if (a=3)
                frase <="pastel";
        }
        if (opc==3)
        {
            printf("paises\n");
            a = rand() %3 + 1;
            if (a=1)
                frase <="peru";
            if (a=2)
                frase <="brasil";
            if (a=3)
                frase <="egipto";
        }
    }
```

`

Comment: Please supply a [mre].  In this case we particular need to know what `frase`.  You copy a string with `strcpy(frase, "pato");`.

Comment: Some problems: Firstly `if (a=1)` needs to use  `==`. Secondly, `frase <="peru"` what do you think the `<=` operator is supposed to do?

Comment: It's ok to have list of if statements which means a will be tested 3 times in each block, but when they are mutually exclusive you usually do `if(...) else if(...) ...` so you get 1, 2 or 3 tests.  Consider using `switch(a) case 1: ...; break; case 2: ...; break;`.  In this case you map a number to a string which can write most directly with an initializer `(const char *[]) { "pato", "ganso", ...}[a]`.

Comment: Where did you learn that `<=` is assignment operator in C?

Answer (score 2):

I suggest you solve this by modeling your data.  In this case with a array of structs.  Then you index into to obtain the relevant data:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <time.h>

int main() {
    struct {
        const char *opc;
        const char **frase;
    } data[] = {
        {"Animales", (const char *[]) { "pato", "ganso", "avispa" }},
        {"comida", (const char *[]) { "pasta", "pizza", "pastel" }},
        {"paises", (const char *[]) { "peru", "brasil", "egipto" }}
    };
    srand(time(0));
    int opc = rand() % 3;
    printf("lvl 1 %s %s\n", data[opc].opc, data[opc].frase[rand() % 3]);
    return 0;
}
```

If you have a lot of data put the data in a file and write a function to build the struct at start-up.  A special case of this approach is to store the data in a lightweight database like SQLite, then you can query for the relevant data at run-time or load it all it upon start-up.

You many no longer need to copy the frase, but if you want to use a strcpy:

```
char frase[100];
strcpy(frase, data[opc].frase[rand() % 3]);
```

Answer (score 0):

Multiple things to be improved in the code. The `if(a=1)` should be changed to `==`. Not sure what you mean by `frase<="pato"`, `strcpy` or `strncpy` should be used. Please refer the following sample code.

```
void copytoarray(char *array, char *word, unsigned int len)
{
    if(array == NULL || word == NULL)
    {
        return;
    }
    strncpy(array, word, len);
}

int main(void) {
    char frase[15] = {'\0'};
    int a, lvl =1;
    int opc =1;
    if(lvl==1)
    {
        printf("lvl 1\n");
        if (opc==1)
        {
            printf("Animales\n");
            a = rand() %3 + 1;
            printf("%d\n", a);
            if (a==1)
                copytoarray(frase, "pato", strlen("pato"));
            if (a==2)
                copytoarray(frase, "ganso", strlen("ganso"));
            if (a==3)
                copytoarray(frase, "avispa", strlen("avispa"));
        }
    }
    printf("Word: %s\n ",frase);
}
```

Comment: As the value of `a` does not change, it seems that you really want `else if (a == 2)` and the same for `3`. A switch statement would make sense here as well.